# PHP dBase as an alternative to SQLite

Tags: php, database, sqlite, nosql, dbase

I have read several comments here that dBase is a dead system and no one use it anymore. I compared dBase and SQLite in php, and in my test dBase has many advantages over SQLite and similar systems:

1. Its database file is much smaller
2. Writing to the file is very faster with using a lesser amount of memory
3. Growing the file size has a negligible effect on the query.

I admit that SQLite has a wider range of commands for a better flexibility; but what can be the reason of unreliability or incapability of dBase which sent it to the background?

I have no idea about concurrent connections (though SQLite has serious limitations too). Please comment on this issue.

Summary: Apart from functionality, I just wanted to know what is possible disadvantage of dBase in performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with a single table then you might not find much difference (aside from the lack of SQL command support in dBase), but as soon as you start using relational data and having multiple related tables, use of dBase falls apart. You have to glue all your relationships together in code with dBase where with SQLite you can have full foreign key support and have relational dependencies.

Some might raise the objection that an InterBase server allows you to have relationships with dBase, but that is really outside the scope of what you're saying.

Summary: for single tables, maybe not much difference, for multiple, related tables, lots of of advantage to SQL-based systems like SQLite.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I wanted to compare dBase with NO-SQL database systems. Apart from functionality, I just wanted to know what is disadvantage of dBase in performance.

Comment: @Ali LOL, dbase has nothing to do with a "NO-SQL" buzzword. It's more like berkley-style key-value databases.

Comment: BerkeleyDB is not a NO-SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

Performance is not an issue for sandbox databases. They all the same.

Same for the "features". Yes, you can waste some time to find some difference. Then eventually your data size will grow up and you will move to some adult DBMS.